How to remove/hide '_version_' field in solr response?
I am working with Apache Solr and I need to hide or remove the version field from the search response. I have tried using the fl (field list) parameter to exclude the version field, but I am encountering issues.
Problem
When I execute a query, I still see the version field in the response, and I am receiving the following error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"

Query Example
Here’s the query I am using:
http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core/select?q=*:*&fl=*,-_version_

Configuration Details
Solr Version: 8.11.3
Schema Configuration: Not explicitly defining version as it's managed internally.
Field Types: Confirmed no mismatch in field types.
Question
How can I properly configure Solr to hide or remove the version field from the search response? Is there a different approach or configuration setting that I might be missing?
Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I don't think the -<field name> syntax is supported? Where did you see that as an example? You'll have to explicitly mention the fields you want, or use wildcards that match all other fields (a*,b*, etc.).
